# ReactJS: Conditionally add className using dot operator

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

With ReactJS I am using SCSS. I use `import classes from './component1.module.scss';` and then access class names using `className={classes.password}`. However, how can I add more classes to the element dynamically based on conditions in this format?

Comment: Use ternaries within the braces, it's simple JS? right

Comment: @Temp O'rary Check the answer that I provided. This technique is used a lot in React. :) Do vote and accept if this answer is helpful ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While ternary operators would work for this, if you have more than a few instances where you need to use this type of logic, you can create a function that will accept a list of class names and return the truthy values.

```js
const cx = (...args) => args.filter(Boolean).join(' ')

<Component className={cx(classes.password, special && classes.specialPassword)} />
```

If you don't want to write your own `cx` function, you could also one of the following libraries which provide the same features and more:

1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames
2. https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx

Answer (score 0):

That how we achieve this from JSX.

```
className={`${isStateValue ? classes.password: classes.password2 classes.password3}`}
```

This is the ternary operator being used. you can even use nested ternary also if you have more conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use backticks and ternary operators inside **${}** and do conditions inside it.

```
className={`${props.password ? classes.password : '404class'}`}
className={`${props.password && classes.password}`}
```